How can I use the Google Navigation SDK in an Android Kotlin app to implement background route tracking without a user interface?
How can I use the Google Navigation SDK in an Android Kotlin app to implement background route tracking without a user interface? I want to receive the route and waypoints, start monitoring the trip in the background, and access information like the remaining time to the next waypoint and other navigation features but without ui and the code wont be needed in MainActivity but its class could be called there to initialise the navigation sdk.
I tried to follow the code in google navigation ask tutorial but still background activity is not working even separating sdk init functionionality from main activity is causing errors
here is my code

import android.Manifest
import android.content.Context
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Looper
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
import com.google.android.libraries.navigation.NavigationApi
import com.google.android.libraries.navigation.NavigationView
import com.google.android.libraries.navigation.Navigator
import com.google.android.libraries.navigation.SimulationOptions
import com.google.android.libraries.navigation.Waypoint
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

class NavigationManager(
    private val context: Context,
    private val navView: NavigationView,
    private val onNavigatorReady: (Navigator) -> Unit
) {
    private var mNavigator: Navigator? = null
    private var arrivalListener: Navigator.ArrivalListener? = null
    private var routeChangedListener: Navigator.RouteChangedListener? = null
    private var navigatorScope: InitializedNavScope? = null
    private var pendingNavActions = mutableListOf<InitializedNavRunnable>()

    /**
     * Initializes the Navigation API and sets up necessary listeners.
     */
    fun initializeNavigation() {
        // Ensure necessary permissions are granted
        if (!checkPermissionGranted(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Location permission is required", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            return
        }

        // Initialize the Navigation SDK
        NavigationApi.getNavigator(context, object : NavigationApi.NavigatorListener {
            override fun onNavigatorReady(navigator: Navigator) {
                val scope = InitializedNavScope(navigator)
                navigatorScope = scope
                pendingNavActions.forEach { block -> scope.block() }
                pendingNavActions.clear()

                mNavigator = navigator

                // Set up navigation listeners
                registerNavigationListeners()

                // Call the callback when the navigator is ready
                onNavigatorReady(navigator)

                // Set up the map to follow the user's location
                navView.getMapAsync { googleMap ->
                    googleMap.followMyLocation(GoogleMap.CameraPerspective.TILTED)
                }

                // Simulate vehicle location in debug mode
                if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                    mNavigator?.simulator?.setUserLocation(MainActivity.startLocation)
                }

                // Initialize the first navigation (e.g., to Trafalgar Square)
                navigateToPlace(MainActivity.TRAFALGAR_SQUARE)
            }

            override fun onError(errorCode: Int) {
                handleNavigatorError(errorCode)
            }
        })
    }

    private fun checkPermissionGranted(permissionToCheck: String): Boolean =
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permissionToCheck) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED

    private fun navigateToPlace(placeId: String) {
        val waypoint = try {
            Waypoint.builder().setPlaceIdString(placeId).build()
        } catch (e: Waypoint.UnsupportedPlaceIdException) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Unsupported place ID", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            return
        }

        withNavigatorAsync {
            val pendingRoute = mNavigator?.setDestination(waypoint)
            pendingRoute?.setOnResultListener { code ->
                when (code) {
                    Navigator.RouteStatus.OK -> startGuidance()
                    else -> Toast.makeText(context, "Error starting guidance: $code", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun startGuidance() {
        mNavigator?.setAudioGuidance(Navigator.AudioGuidance.VOICE_ALERTS_AND_GUIDANCE)
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            mNavigator?.simulator?.simulateLocationsAlongExistingRoute(
                SimulationOptions().speedMultiplier(5f)
            )
        }
        mNavigator?.startGuidance()
    }

    private fun registerNavigationListeners() {
        withNavigatorAsync {
            arrivalListener = Navigator.ArrivalListener {
                Toast.makeText(context, "User has arrived at the destination!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                mNavigator?.clearDestinations()
                if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                    mNavigator?.simulator?.unsetUserLocation()
                }
            }
            mNavigator?.addArrivalListener(arrivalListener)

            routeChangedListener = Navigator.RouteChangedListener {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Route changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            mNavigator?.addRouteChangedListener(routeChangedListener)
        }
    }

    private fun withNavigatorAsync(block: InitializedNavRunnable) {
        val navigatorScope = navigatorScope
        if (navigatorScope != null) {
            navigatorScope.block()
        } else {
            pendingNavActions.add(block)
        }
    }

    private fun handleNavigatorError(errorCode: Int) {
        when (errorCode) {
            NavigationApi.ErrorCode.NOT_AUTHORIZED -> {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Error: API key is not authorized", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
            NavigationApi.ErrorCode.TERMS_NOT_ACCEPTED -> {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Error: Terms not accepted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
            else -> {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Error: $errorCode", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
    }

    fun onStop() {
        mNavigator?.clearDestinations()
        mNavigator?.cleanup()
        arrivalListener?.let { mNavigator?.removeArrivalListener(it) }
        routeChangedListener?.let { mNavigator?.removeRouteChangedListener(it) }
    }

    fun onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
        navView.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
    }

    fun onStart() {
        navView.onStart()
    }

    fun onResume() {
        navView.onResume()
    }

    fun onPause() {
        navView.onPause()
    }

    fun onStop() {
        navView.onStop()
    }

    fun onDestroy() {
        navView.onDestroy()
        onStop()  // Clean up navigator listeners and resources
    }
}
``


The Navigation SDK’s purpose is for turn-by-turn navigation. If you really want to monitor your drivers during a trip, Mobility Solutions is more suited for your use case. You’ll have to contact sales as this is not publicly available.
